# Add an additional line in a cell in a table

Tags: tables

I have the following problem: I am creating a table that i would like to print and write into it by hand. For that use i need the following. I want some cells to be divided by a diagonal line. However I dont want the cell itself to be divided plus the line should not split the cell symmetrically. To be precise, the line should go from the middle of the bottom of the cell to the middle of the right side of the cell. I tried to use tikz, but it doesnt produce the line described above.

Here is my try with tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[landscape=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{||c||c||c|c||}
    \hline
    {\hspace{2cm} Spieltag\hspace{1cm}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Ergebnisse} & & \\
    \hline
     & & : \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] \draw (0.5,0) -- (1,0.5); & \\
     \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides environments similar to the classical environments (`{tabular}`, `{pmatrix}`, etc.) but with PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns. Then, it's possible to use TikZ (in the so-called `\CodeAfter`) to draw whatever rule you want.

However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[landscape=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{||c||c||c|c||}
    \hline
    {\hspace{2cm} Spieltag\hspace{1cm}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Ergebnisse} & & \\
    \hline
     & & & \\
     \hline
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (3-|3.5) -- (2.5-|4) ;
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]